# react-countup slowdown count on last sequences

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using react-countup package I want to slowdown counting on last sequences like this: [see ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJgOV.gif)

how is it possible?
my code looks like this rn

```
   <div className="nox-number home-page-numbers-number">
                            <CountUp
                                decimals={isDecimal ? 1 : 0}
                                duration={1}
                                end={parsedNum}
                                onEnd={() => {
                                    setActive(false)
                                }}
                                start={parsedNum > 10 ? parsedNum - 10 : 0}
                            >
                                {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
                                    <VisibilitySensor
                                        active={active}
                                        delayedCall
                                        onChange={(isVisible) =>
                                            isVisible ? start() : null
                                        }
                                    >
                                        <span ref={countUpRef} />
                                    </VisibilitySensor>
                                )}
                            </CountUp>
                            {removeNumberFromString(number)}
                        </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve the same functionality without using the library ?

Comment: It will be great too

Comment: I meant, you didn't mention your problem where you're stuck because you are already using `react-countup` library to slow down last counting. What's problem are you facing ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJgOV.gif I want to achieve this but my result is linear and won't slow down at the end

Comment: Try this `<CountUp
          start={0}
          end={100000}
          duration={3}
        /> `